# SOAP - how to Add SKU to Bundle product 'items' array

Tags: soap, bundled-product, bundle

I'm using SOAP for reading orders from Magento to insert them into an internal accounting system. I have a problem to decode Bundle products. Internal accounting system does not know anything about these bundles since they're created in Magento only. I get the data for Items and I have some data in product_options field, but it's not complete enough:

```
s:14:"bundle_options";a:2:
{
i:445;a:3:{
s:9:"option_id";s:3:"445";s:5:"label";s:6:"Finish";s:5:"value";a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:5:"title";s:17:"Sana 5 Arm Chrome";s:3:"qty";i:1;s:5:"price";d:8.79;}}
}
i:446;a:3:{s:9:"option_id";s:3:"446";s:5:"label";s:4:"Lamp";s:5:"value";a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:5:"title";s:31:"2896 LED 3.5W Clear Tube L1 Cap";s:3:"qty";i:5;s:5:"price";d:29.15;}}
}
}
```

In this serialized array, I can read 445 and 446 as product options ID's but these are internal ID's from one of magento DB tables, so there's not much I can do with them.

I'd like to add SKU field to this SOAP readout - is there any way to modify SOAP export to add more fields?

Answer (score 2):

unserialize the array and then get the product from the products ID.  Then, get the sku from this product.  Add the sku to the array and serialize it again.